# Nvd3 Pie Chart Label Issues

Tags: angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 pie chart,I have one issue,My pie chart labels are not aligning correctly inside the Pie chart![,][1]

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the nvd3 css file in to your project?